# How to iterate through HTML entities with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have the following HTML [below].  I am trying to iterate through all DOM with class="gmvcRow", and grab  the text in all of the "gmvcCell" for each 'gmvcRow'.  I would like to place all the text in an array(['firstname', 'lastname', 'dob', 'city']). And i would like to place this array into another array that holds "arrays of gmvcRow".  My attempt is below but i am still not successful.  I understand that the text in 'gmvcCell' is in itself another label node.

```
 <div class="gmvcRow">
      <div class="gmvcCell">firtname</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">lastname</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">dob</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">city</div>
 </div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
```

my code:

```
 var gmvcRowArray = document.getElementsByClassName('gmvcRow');
 console.log('number of records: ' + gmvcRowArray.length);

 // Master array
var masterArray = [];

// Iterate through array
for(var i=0; i<gmvcRowArray.length; i++){
    // Iterate through all childNodes
    var rowArray = [];


    for(var c=0; c<gmvcRowArray[i].childNodes.length; c++){
        c = c + 1; // skip non text node
        console.log('c: '+c);

        if(gmvcRowArray[i].childNodes[c] != null){
            var value = gmvcRowArray[i].childNodes[c].innerHTML;

            rowArray.push(value);
            //console.log('rowArray.length: '+rowArray.length);
            console.log('value: '+value);
        }


        c = c - 1;
    }
    // Add row to master array
    masterArray.push(rowArray);
    console.log('masterArray.lengh: '+masterArray.length);
}
```

Comment: you could use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `childNodes` makes it harder than needed, since it also selects text nodes.

Instead use some of the ES6 features, which lead to concise code:

```js
var arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.gmvcRow'), row =>
    Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('.gmvcCell'), cell => cell.textContent)
);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class="gmvcRow">
  <div class="gmvcCell">firstname</div>
  <div class="gmvcCell">lastname</div>
  <div class="gmvcCell">dob</div>
  <div class="gmvcCell">city</div>
</div>
<div class="gmvcRow">
  <div class="gmvcCell">Helene</div>
  <div class="gmvcCell">Johnson</div>
  <div class="gmvcCell">11/11/1995</div>
  <div class="gmvcCell">Paris</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) ...

Comment: Yes, there is... But the requirement was to "*...grab the text in all of the "gmvcCell" for each 'gmvcRow'..."*, which is not quite the same as grabbing the text from all the `.children`.

Comment: Ah true. Forgive my comment then.

Answer (score 1):

Quick sample for 1-level nesting

```
var rows = Array.from(document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('.gmvcRow'));

const result = rows.map(row => {
    return Array
        .from(row.querySelectorAll('.gmvcCell'))
        .map(cell => cell.innerText);
});

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snba2qsf/

After all you can filter result to exclude empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

In your Script: Just check the value before adding to row array whether Is not null and not undefined.

```
if(value != null || value != undefined)
{
rowArray.push(value.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer using `querySelectorAll`

```js
var gmvcRowArray = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.gmvcRow').forEach((el, idxRow) =>{
var gmvcCellArray = [];
 el.querySelectorAll('.gmvcCell')
  .forEach((el) =>{
   gmvcCellArray.push(el.innerText);
  });
  gmvcRowArray.push(gmvcCellArray)
})
console.log(gmvcRowArray)
```

```html
 <div class="gmvcRow">
      <div class="gmvcCell">Name1</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">lastname1</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">dob1</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">city1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="gmvcRow">
      <div class="gmvcCell">Name2</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">lastname2</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">dob2</div>
      <div class="gmvcCell">city2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
 <div class="gmvcRow"></div>
```